# How does Shopify manage hundreds of thousands domains to one IP

Tags: domain-name-system, routing, web-server, ip

I am wondering how does Shopify routes and provides SSL certificates for the hundred of thousands of domains that are pointed to their IP Address `23.227.38.32`.I am trying to build a similar service as Spotify and was wondering how to achieve this.After that,how does it curate the content for the specific domain.Does the web server look up the host domain and then render the appropriate content?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. DNS wildcarding - `*.myshopify.com` is a CNAME to `shops.myshopify.com` which has an A record for `23.227.38.64`. This is a Cloudflare anycast IP address.
2. Host based routing - the server inspects the `host` request header and then renders the appropriate "shop".
3. Dynamic TLS - if you have to ask about 1 and 2, then you shouldn't probably attempt 3 alone. They leverage Cloudflare to provide certificates, which is a simple and safe method to do it. If you wanted to build your own, take a look at the `HTTP-01 challenge` spec. https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-acme-acme-01